# After hosting angular application on iis server direct url is not working it or page refresh on enter is not working

Tags: iis-7, angular2-routing, angular4-router

Please find web.config code

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

whenever I enter URL ex myapp/orderform it always renders to home or give errors that file or directory does not exist.